# Upload image on S3 API using multer returns undefined

Tags: node.js, api, amazon-s3, upload, multer

I am building an API for uploading images and storing them directly on S3 storage. To do that, I use Postman.Method is POST and the input type is file.When I use req.files or req.file I get undefined.

Utils.js:

```
getS3SignUrl: function( uri ){
   return s3_client.getSignedUrl('putObject',{Bucket:config.aws.bucket,Key:uri,ACL :"public-read"})
}
```

And in the main file I use these:

```
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');
var upload = require('multer')();
var utils = require('../service/utils.js');

router.post('/edit-profile', upload.single('newfile'), function(req, res) {
    console.log(req.file);  
  });
});
```

In console, I get undefined, but when I use debugger and req.body, I get this: [image]

So, it seems I have it in req.body, but how can I take it from here?

Comment: Try using the `upload` method of S3 instead of `putObject`.

Comment: Thanks! I used multer-s3 module and it worked. I was able to upload file on s3 storage. Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Beside multer, I installed and included multerS3 module:

```
var multerS3 = require('multer-s3');
```

Then, I configured it. I, also, tested it with a form on which I applied `enctype="multipart/form-data"`

```
router.post('/ceva', multer({  storage: multerS3({ s3: s3_client, bucket: "****", acl: '**',  metadata: function (req, file, cb) {  cb(null, {fieldName: file.fieldname}); }, key: function (req, file, cb) {
      cb(null, "users/10/1"); } }) }).single('newfile'), function(req, res) {
    console.log(req.files);
    res.send('da');
});
```

Thus, the files had been uploaded successfully on S3 storage.

Comment: console.log(req.files[0].location); will give you the signedUrl for the file